# how to determine the total number matches of data using python in excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

how to determine the total matches of data using python excel? For E.g. X,Y found in "Ameloginin" is considered as a count of 1 as it matches baby Johnathon value of X,Y or partial match
Baby Johnathon D8S1179 value is 11,12 and M1 D8S1179 value is 11,16 so +1 as there is a match of 11 on both ends.

Link to full data that is unclean
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/de3384467a25b7148255c6d9ef022c0f20220203043147/95d780

Comment: Open excel, hit "Find and replace", use a simple string or regex to replace?

Comment: Also did you mean to say "*separated by **commas***"?

Comment: yes separated by commas

Comment: unfortunately, i require a script

Answer (score 0):

If you can update it use the string replace function in python

```
stringvariable.replace(' ','')
```

That should do it

Comment: can u help me on how to read the excel in python before I do this thanks

Comment: so you can get started here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/